# Using jWebSockets channel plug-in with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

Is there any example demonstrating the use of  jWebSockets channel plug-in with node.js or is there any equivalent of jWebSockets channel plug-in in node.js.how can a Message server be implemented on node.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://socket.io/

Look at the example on the front page it's really simple.

Comment: is jwebSockets equivalent ot socket.io

Comment: I haven't used jwebSockets before but from a Google search I find that it's a websocket server. socket.io is more than that. it's a server, websocket clients can connect to it but it does a lot more by using alternatives for browsers that don't support websockets.

Comment: jwebsocket also has a javascript client and a concept of plugins, for different use cases. You can write your own custom plugin